# Make apache2.conf immutable?

Tags: apache-2.4

I think the answer is no... I've already demonstrated a good reason to be no, I forgot that I had done this to apache2.conf and could not figure out why I could not save any changes.

Should I make apache2.conf immutable via `chattr +i` and if so, how do I make changes to it as root?

Comment: Do what you like. I could see arguments in either direction.

Answer (score 3):

Don't waste your time.  If someone gains access to your system to the extent that they would be able to write to your apache2.conf file then you've been had.  Making the conf file immutable won't change that.